# what is _ctl0 javascript and when we use this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

what is this `_ctl0` in javascript and how we use this.
in this they are using for storing the value of current tab due to it is postback.
actually I am creating tabs using jquery,html and css not using jquery ui. I am facing the postaback problem inn tabs. when I am in second tab it is move into first tab not come to second tab. below for this I m storing the current tab value using `_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection`. is this  the right method.

one more thing how I can find current tab index that I save during postback.

```
if ($('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val() == "") {
            $('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val(location.hash)
        }

        $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + $('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val() + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));

        window.location.href = window.location.href.toString() + $active.attr('href');
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class='tabs'>
                <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div id='tab1' class=tabss>
                <ul class= "set2"> 
                    <li>  test 1<asp:TextBox runat="server"   /></li>
                    <li>  test 2<asp:TextBox runat="server"   /></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div id='tab2' class=tabss>
                <ul class= "set2"> 
                    <li>  test 3<asp:TextBox runat="server"   /></li>
                    <li>  test 4<asp:TextBox runat="server"   /></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div id='tab3' class=tabss>
                <ul class= "set2"> 
                    <li>  test 5<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test5" /></li>
                    <li>  test 6<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test6" /></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

Comment: your HTML code please?

Comment: can you provide me your all code on some other link or in JSFiddle?

Comment: They are ClientIDs generated by ASP.NET engine. A [good blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx) to read

Comment: @Satpal Actually OP wants the solution for his issue. its question is not about what is Ctr0_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_ctl0_` is prefixed for uniqueness of server side id. As in server side code many controls can have same id.

You can use

```
$('#<%= hdnCurrentTabSelection.ClientID %>').val()
```

Innstead of

```
$('#_ctl0_hdnCurrentTabSelection').val()
```

The `ClientID` will give you exactly what asp.net will generate.

If you are using .Net Framework 4 and above then you can also using [ClientIDMode="static"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to keep the same html control id as of server control

> The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If the
>   control is a naming container, the control is used as the top of the
>   hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it contains,
>   [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET engine sets the ID values at runtime for those controls whose IDs have not been explicitly set. It uses the naming pattern ctlXX, where XX is a sequentially increasing integer value. So, in case of nested master pages you will get prefix as ctlxx where xx will be incremented value.

Control's Id value is prefixed with the master page's ID value, ctl00. The net effect is an id attribute value consisting of the ID values of the master page, the ContentPlaceHolder control, and the Control itself.

Please refer http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs for more information.

To get and set asp.net controls value in jquery use :

(Get control value ) : $('[id$=ControlId]').val(); and 
   (Set control value ) : $('[id$=ControlId]').val('Value');

To get and set html controls value in jquery use :

(Get control value ) : $('#ControlId').val(); and 
   (Set control value ) : $('#ControlId').val('Value');